# NPM error on running protractor tests (EPERM: operation not permitted)

Tags: node.js, npm, protractor

I run in these error when trying to run protractor tests:

```
C:\nodejs\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:155
                throw e;
                ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:/$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-18'
    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:886:3)
    at GlobSync._readdir (C:\nodejs\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\glob\sync.js:288:41)
    at GlobSync._readdirInGlobStar (C:\nodejs\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\glob\sync.js:267:20)
    at GlobSync._readdir (C:\nodejs\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\glob\sync.js:276:17)
    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (C:\nodejs\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\glob\sync.js:350:22)
    at GlobSync._process (C:\nodejs\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\glob\sync.js:130:10)
    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (C:\nodejs\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\glob\sync.js:383:10)
    at GlobSync._process (C:\nodejs\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\glob\sync.js:130:10)
    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (C:\nodejs\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\glob\sync.js:383:10)
    at GlobSync._process (C:\nodejs\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\glob\sync.js:130:10) {
  errno: -4048,
  syscall: 'scandir',
  code: 'EPERM',
  path: 'C:/$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-18'
```

I tryed to reinstall protractor, nodejs, npm. I also tryed to clear npm cache and node_modules folders. Nothing changed :(

I've installed latest npm and nodejs version.

Could anyone could help me?

Comment: Why is there a absolute path to `Recycle bin` ?

Comment: I don't know, I never added this path or modify the protractor node modules...

Answer (score 0):

**I recommend not to do this change because your are overriding node_module Package file.**

1. Go to your node_modules folder and dive to this url: `<your_path>\node_modules\globule\node_modules\glob\glob.js`
2. Search for:

```
if (this.sync) {
  var er, entries
  try {
    entries = fs.readdirSync(abs)
  } catch (e) {
    er = e
  }
}
```

or go to line 577

3. Change:

```
entries = fs.readdirSync(abs)
```

To:

```
entries = fs.readdirSync('abs')
```